# How to refresh the second hidden dropdown menu based on first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to refresh the second hidden dropdown menu based on first one?When i select an option from first dropdown the second dropdown appears and after selecting from second one i got text content but again when i select an option from first dropdown, previous text content didn't hide.Next text content appears below first one. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/pratyush141/VtFCR/

```
<select id="circle">
<option value="">select </option>
<option value="Bihar">Bihar </option>
<option value="Assam">Assam</option>
</select>



<select id="assam" style="display:none" >
<option value="">Pick one</option>
<option value="1">Top up</option>
<option value="2">sms</option>
<option value="3">data</option>
</select>
<select id="bihar" style="display:none">
<option value="">Pick one</option>
<option value="1">data</option>
<option value="2">sms</option>
<option value="3">top up</option>
</select>
<div id="brtopup" style="display:none">topup</div>
<div id="brsms" style="display:none">sms</div>
<div id="brdata" style="display:none">data</div>
<div id="astopup" style="display:none">topup</div>
<div id="assms" style="display:none">sms</div>
<div id="asdata" style="display:none">data</div>


$("#circle").change(function() {
var control = $(this);

if (control.val() == "Assam") {
    $("#assam").show();   
} else { 
 $("#assam").hide();   
}
if (control.val() == "Bihar") {
    $("#bihar").show();   
} else { 
 $("#bihar").hide();   
}
 });


$("#bihar").change(function() {
var control = $(this);

if (control.val() == "1") {
    $("#brdata").show();   
} else { 
 $("#brdata").hide();   
}
if (control.val() == "2") {
    $("#brsms").show();   
} else { 
 $("#brsms").hide();   
}
if (control.val() == "3") {
    $("#brtopup").show();   
} else { 
 $("#brtopup").hide();   
}


 });
 $("#assam").change(function() {
var control = $(this);

if (control.val() == "1") {
    $("#astopup").show();   
} else { 
 $("#astopup").hide();   
}
if (control.val() == "2") {
    $("#assms").show();   
} else { 
 $("#assms").hide();   
}
if (control.val() == "3") {
    $("#asdata").show();   
} else { 
 $("#asdata").hide();   
}

$('#assam').trigger("chosen:updated");
 });
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/pratyush141/VtFCR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class to the different groups of assam and bihar :

```
<div id="brtopup" class ="bihar" style="display:none">topup</div>
<div id="brsms" class ="bihar" style="display:none">sms</div>
<div id="brdata" class ="bihar" style="display:none">data</div>
<div id="astopup" class ="assam" style="display:none">topup</div>
<div id="assms" class ="assam" style="display:none">sms</div>
<div id="asdata" class ="assam" style="display:none">data</div>
```

and then you can hide the whole class groups instantly:

```
if (control.val() == "Assam") {
        $("#assam").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#assam").hide();
     $(".assam").hide();
    }
    if (control.val() == "Bihar") {
        $("#bihar").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#bihar").hide();
     $(".bihar").hide();
    }
     });
```

### [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/VtFCR/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in JS

```
$("#circle").change(function() {
    var control = $(this);

    if (control.val() == "Assam") {
        $("#assam").show();   
    } else { 
        $("#assam").hide(); 
        $("#astopup").hide();//add three lines
        $("#assms").hide();
        $("#asdata").hide();
    }
    if (control.val() == "Bihar") {
        $("#bihar").show();   
    } else { 
        $("#bihar").hide();  
        $("#brtopup").hide();//add three lines
        $("#brsms").hide();
        $("#brdata").hide();
    }
     });


    $("#bihar").change(function() {
    var control = $(this);

    if (control.val() == "1") {
        $("#brdata").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#brdata").hide();   
    }
if (control.val() == "2") {
        $("#brsms").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#brsms").hide();   
    }
if (control.val() == "3") {
        $("#brtopup").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#brtopup").hide();   
    }


 });
$("#assam").change(function() {
    var control = $(this);

    if (control.val() == "1") {
        $("#astopup").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#astopup").hide();   
    }
if (control.val() == "2") {
        $("#assms").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#assms").hide();   
    }
if (control.val() == "3") {
        $("#asdata").show();   
    } else { 
     $("#asdata").hide();   
    }

$('#assam').trigger("chosen:updated");
 });
```